# Remove non alphanumeric from method GET form url

Tags: php, regex, get

I have a `method="GET"` form resulting in foo.php?id=*userinput* on submission.

I currently use `preg_replace("/\W|_/", "", $_GET['id']);` to remove all non alphanumeric chars in the GET string which works fine backend (adding to database etc (im not inserting to db thats just example)) but the url link does not clean and results in exactly whatever the user inputs plus browser encoding.

So for instants if user inputs `f& oo )(£b$%a&r£1` backed cleans well creating `foobar1` but the url results as `foo.php?id=f%26+oo+)(£b%24%25a%26r£1`

is it possible to clean the url result and if so how?

**Update:**

Submission code:

```
if(!$_GET['id']) {

 header('location: index.php');
 exit;

} else {

 $get_id = preg_replace("/\W|_/", "", $_GET['id']);

}
```

Comment: problem is not with the regex.

Comment: You could redirect but why do you care what the url looks like to someone who tries to hack or spam your form?

Comment: The url will be shared (fb, twitter etc) so would like a clean url.

Comment: You should probably not share if a user sends in garbage on purpose...

Comment: Are you reassigning the replaced url?

Comment: @hwnd, as I do not understand what you mean I gusss not.

Comment: Can you show your code where you're applying above regex?

Comment: Its just a simple `if else` but first post updated.

Comment: Can you show `var_dump($get_id);` after `preg_replace`.

Comment: `string 'foobar1' (length=7)`

Comment: Well that means it worked since it remove everything else?

Comment: As I said in first post it cleans backend for adding to database etc but not the url its self, the url remains as whatever the user inputs plus browser encoding.

Comment: That is because you didn't change the URL and do a redirect in your PHP code.

Comment: How is this achieved, i tried `header('location: foo.php?id='.$get_id);` but get a 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1):

You can use this PHP code after your `preg_replace` method to do a URL redirect:

```
if(!$_GET['id']) {
   header('location: index.php');
   exit;
} else if ( preg_match('/[\W_]/', $_GET['id']) ) {
    $get_id = preg_replace('/[\W_]/', "", $_GET['id']);
    header('Location: ' $_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"] . $get_id);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Now I get `The page isn't redirecting properly` (FF), or `This webpage has a redirect loop` (chrome).

Comment: Now fixed by creating a new file and separating submission and cleaning and redirecting to new file

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how redirect should be handled in code.